# Stopping background services during an android activity

Tags: java, android, mobile, background-service

I am developing an android game right now, and it requires very precise timing and synchronization. That said, it is essential that there is no lag during the game. However I sometimes get lag spikes in the game, and I know its not the GC because I have run the ddms tool, and eliminated all the GC calls. However, I do see alot of background services popping up in my ddms logcat. Is there anyway to pause all services when my game is running?

I would appreciate any other solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to pause all services
>   when my game is running?

No. However, background operations (particularly from other apps) generally run in a priority class that limit them to 5-10% of CPU.